# Tangent plane for level curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $$f(x,y,z):\frac{x+2y+4xy}{5z^2 + 3}$$ what's the level curve going through the point $$p(6,1,-1)$$ and what's the tangent plane at that point to that level curve?

What I've done is I've entered $p$ into my function, I get 4, so the level curve I am interested in is $f(x,y,z) = 4$, right? Then I am not sure how to proceed. How does one locate the tangent plane ... of a level curve?

Answer (score 2):

For a function on 3-space, it's a level-surface rather than a level curve, but you're right, it's at level 4.

The other fact that you need to know is that hte gradient of your function is perpendicular to the level surface. Since
$$
\nabla f (x, y, z) = ( (1+4y)/(5z^2 + 3), 2/(5z^2+3), -(x+2y+4xy)/(5z^2+3)^2)
$$
we get
$$
\nabla f (6, -1, 1) = ( (-3)/8, 2/8, -6/64) \\
= (1/64) (-24, 16, -6)
$$

So you have a plane through $(6, -1, 1)$ with normal vector proportional to $(-24, 16, -6)$. Can you find its equation?